# Append a column to an existing Datatable with dynamically bound values

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I have the following Datatable in Vb

```
   Id            Price
  -----          -------
   1231           100
   1232           150
   1235           150
```

I want to add a third column to that datatable called `flag`, with values of the last digit of `Id`

Like the following:

```
    Id               Price         Flag
   -----            ------       ----------
    1231             100             1
    1232             150             2
    1235             150             5
```

How do I append a column to an existing Datatable, with dynamically bound values?

Is there a way I can do this without using a For Loop?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You first need to add a `DataColumn`:

```
table.Columns.Add("Flag", typeof(int));
```

Now you just need to add the values accordingly:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int ID = row.Field<int>("ID");
    string lastDigit = ID.ToString().Last().ToString();
    row.SetField("Flag", int.Parse(lastDigit));
}
```

The only way to avoid a loop is to fill it with these values in the first place, for example if it's filled from database. So even if a [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) approach existed(which is not the case here) that would cause a loop in the framework.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a for Loop?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut: no, there isn't. And even if there "was" a way(like with [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), the framework would use a loop implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can do this without using a For Loop?

Yes, add a computed column with the following [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[id] % 10
```

Example (vb.net):

```vb
Using table As New DataTable()

    table.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Decimal))

    table.Rows.Add(1231I, 100D)
    table.Rows.Add(1232I, 150D)
    table.Rows.Add(1235I, 150D)

    'Add a new computed column:                    expr
    table.Columns.Add("Flag", GetType(Integer), "[id] % 10")

    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}    {1}    {2}", row.ItemArray)
    Next

End Using
```

Example (C#):

```cs
using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
{

    table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));

    table.Rows.Add(1231, 100M);
    table.Rows.Add(1232, 150M);
    table.Rows.Add(1235, 150M);

    //Add a new computed column:              expr
    table.Columns.Add("Flag", typeof(int), "[id] % 10");

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}    {1}    {2}", row.ItemArray);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1231    100    1
1232    150    2
1235    150    5
```

Comment: Debugging the part where I add a computed column is taking too long with no response. Why do you think?

Comment: How many rows? I tested with table containing 1 million rows, it took ~2 seconds.