# C# Adding dynamic column and rows in Datatable

Tags: c#

I tried to add values to DataTable columns by vertically in loops.

But output doesn't looks good as expected.

```
DataTables dynamictable = new DataTable()
foreach (DataColumn cl in dataTable.Columns)
{
   dynamictable.Columns.Add(cl.ToString());
   List<string> plainList = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[cl].ToString()).ToList();

   for (int i=0; i< plainList.Count(); i++)
   {
       DataRow row = dynamictable.NewRow();
       row[cl.ToString()] = plainList[i];   
       enryptedTable.Rows.Add(row);
   }
}
```

Actual Output got from my code:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Append a column to an existing Datatable with dynamically bound values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212764/append-a-column-to-an-existing-datatable-with-dynamically-bound-values) and [How can I dynamically add colums and rows to an empty dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712509/how-can-i-dynamically-add-colums-and-rows-to-an-empty-dataset)

Answer (score 2):

change your code to :

```
DataTable dynamictable = new DataTable();
int col = 0;
foreach (DataColumn cl in dataTable.Columns)
{
    dynamictable.Columns.Add(cl.ToString());
    List<string> plainList = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[cl].ToString()).ToList();
    DataRow row = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < plainList.Count(); i++)
    {
       row = dynamictable.NewRow();
       row[col] = plainList[i];
       dynamictable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    col++;
}
//now set dynamictable to datagridview or .....
```